# JSON object com Array. Migração de swift 2 para swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, alamofire, swift-3

Anteriormente na minha app quando fazia uma chamada ao servidor e caso existisse algum erro eu fazia o seguinte:

```
Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest).responseJSON{
response in if let JSON = response.result.value{
if JSON.count != 0{
let errorList = JSON["responseErrorsList"] as? NSArray
 for error in errorList!{
   let erro: String = error as! String
     switch erro{
       case "EntityRequired":
```

com a migração do swift 2 para swift 4 estou a ter problemas pois o errosList vem a nil no entanto o resultado do JSON é o seguinte:

["Rate": , "Level": , "Code": , "ID": 0, "Zone": , "Address": , "ErrorsListServer": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x17400ba90>(
InvalidCode
)
, "SubZone": ]

Alguem sabe como posso aceder ao campo "ErrorsListServer" e ir buscar os erros que neste caso é "InvalidCode".

O que tenho implementado e não está a resultar é o seguinte:

```
if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: Any]{
    if (JSON as AnyObject).count != 0{
      let errorList = JSON["responseErrorsList"] as? [[String: Any]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Achei resposta á minha pergunta bas fazer os eguinte:

```
if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: Any], 
let errorList = JSON["ErrorsListServer"] as? [String] {
  for error in errorList {
      print(error)
  }
}
```